# Adding a CSS Class to the inner pages of Zend Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

Is it possible to add a CSS class to the inner pages within a Zend Navigation? I am trying to implement [twitter bootstrap navigation dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same requirement for a project. I extended the Menu view helper to do the job and made the code available on [Github](https://github.com/michaelmoussa/zf1-navigation-view-helper-bootstrap)

> [zf1-navigation-view-helper-bootstrap](https://github.com/michaelmoussa/zf1-navigation-view-helper-bootstrap)
>
> **Description**
>
> This Zend Framework View Helper extends the existing
>   Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu view helper to render dropdown menus
>   compatible with the format required in Twitter Bootstrap. The
>   automatic dropdown functionality requires adding various class, id,
>   and data-toggle attributes, which Zend Framework's menu view helper
>   doesn't natively support

Answer (score 1):

You can set the class with the `setUlClass()` method. The following example will set the class to `sub_menu` on all menu items with a depth 2.

```
$this->navigation()->menu()
    ->setUlClass('sub_menu')
    ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
    ->setRenderParents(false)
    ->setMinDepth(2)
    ->setMaxDepth(2);
```

Comment: I am looking to set the inner ul classes.

Comment: Ah, I see. You'll need to implement a partial then.